# Unknown column hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Using Spring and Hibernate I'm getting this exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'user0_.company_ID' in 'field list'
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my mapping file:

```
     <context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="permissionsPackage.Entity" />
<context:component-scan 
base-package="permissionsPackage.dao" />

 <bean id="UserPermissionsDao" class="permissionsPackage.dao.UserPermissionsDao"/>
  <bean id="UserContextDao" class="permissionsPackage.dao.UserContextDao"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
 class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
   destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/permissions?autoReconnect=true"
    p:username="root"
    p:password="root"></bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="permissionsPackage.Entity"/>   
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="session" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils" factory-method="getSession" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory" />
    <constructor-arg value="false" />
    <!-- This is seems to be needed to get rid of the 'No Hibernate Session' error' -->

</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

My user entity looks like this:

```
    @Entity(name = "permissionsPackage.Entity.User")
    @Table(name = "User")
    public class User {

private long Id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
@Column(name = "COMPANYID")
private long companyId;
boolean hasPermission;

public User(Company company, long companyId, String name) {

    this.company = company;
    this.companyId = companyId;
    this.name = name;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public long getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    Id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public long getCompanyId() {
    return companyId;
}

public void setCompanyId(long companyId) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
}
```

I just want to create a simple query that pulls all the details from User. Like this:

```
    String hql = "FROM permissionsPackage.Entity.User";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    List results = query.list();
    return (User) results;
```

I don't understand why it says that it is finding the column beacause I can insert to the table?

Comment: The code you show doesn't compile: there is no company field in User, and that's precisely this hidden field that causes the problem. Show us the real code.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was meant to remove company